# How to add virtual IP to network interface in CentOS?

Tags: centos, network-interface

My CentOS VPS got many IP addresses that I'd like to add to the `eth0` network interface.

Currently `eth0` only got 1 IPv4 address and its other ones doesn't show up.

My searching gives me terms like *IP Alias* but that doesn't seem to apply to CentOS. [The CentOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/VirtualIPAddresses) doesn't really show how it's done.

> `cp /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0`
>
> **Now you can edit the new file ifcfg-eth0:0 and specify the network settings of the virtual interface.**

How do I manually add IPv4 IP addresses to a physical network interface in CentOS 7?

Comment: The Wiki tip you link to does explains how to add to add IP addresses to a network device that persists across reboots. The Wiki could be more verbose and explanatory but the information is there. Can you [edit] the question to highlight the part(s) you're having trouble with.

Comment: Done. *You can now edit the file*. Yes, very much aware that the file is editable, but what to put in it? @AnthonyGeoghegan

Comment: Cool. I've upvoted your question. I was going to add an answer based on referencing the documentation at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-editing_network_configuration_files but it looks like Hunter's answer meets your needs.

Comment: Well, @AnthonyGeoghegan, you link covers more ways of doing it (like scripting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a configuration file called `ifcfg-<interface name>:0` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`

The syntax of the configuration will be like this :

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=x.x.x.x
GATEWAY=x.x.x.x
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
TYPE=Ethernet
```

Then restart the service and you should be good to go.

```
service network restart
```

Comment: What if the gateway is assigned through DHCP?

Comment: Comment out the line which says `GATEWAY` in your config.

Comment: I am sure the issue is me but not seeing how/why.  Using the above template, plug-in necessary values 'service network restart' expected results, but does not persist across boot.  'systemctl restart network' seems to have no effect.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It works for me after I changed `DEVICE="eth0"` to `DEVICE="eth0:0"`

Answer (score 2):

To assign an IP just in your session, volatile until reboot:

```
ip a add 1.2.3.4/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: You can make this answer even more useful by adding a link to the man page of `ip` and by describing what each of the flags are used for in this case.